# Each time I load my application, it attempts to repair the existing install. It is an issue with the vs2008 setup and deployment project

Tags: winforms, deployment, installation, repair

I have created a win forms application that is installed using a setup and deployment project.  During a recent update to the setup and deployment project, I've caused a problem that I can not find the source of.  Each time I click on the shortcut to my project, it runs the setup again.  In effect it is repairing the install each time the shortcut is clicked.

Also, this issue is related to the shortcut that is created by the setup and deployment project.  If I go directly to the console.exe file and run my application it does not attempt to repair it.

Using visual studio 2008 and I have custom actions that run on the install, however I can't see how they could cause the application to repair itself on load.

Thanks

Comment: Update:  When the repair finishes, it goes ahead and loads my console.  I can use the application as is, but there is no need for it to repair on load.

Comment: SOLVED:  This was caused by my custom action.  I needed a file to exist on the client machine for the custom action, and it was deleting the file after it was done with it.  The setup and deployment project uses advertised shortcuts.  When the file was deleted, the shortcut believed that the install was corrupted and it was reinstalling from the MSI.

You can turn off advertised shortcuts with a post build script, but in my case I just stopped deleting the file when I was done with it.

Problem solved.